# Connecting grafana (outside service mesh) to datasource inside the service mesh

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, datasource, grafana, istio

When trying to add a Postgresql data source (running inside the service mesh/ with sidecar) to Grafana (running outside service mesh/ without sidecar), a connection cannot be established, however it is able to translate the fully qualified domain name ({app}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local) into the correct IP address for the service.

I have attempted pinging the grafana pod from the Postgres pod by exec-ing in, which times out but correctly translates the FQDN to the IP address.

Postgres logs do not show any errors or connection attempts, grafana logs show a 500 error when trying to "Save & Test" the datasource in the grafana dashboard.

Expected behaviour is a successful connection to the datasource, would I have to configure a certain istio object to enable the out-of-service-mesh dashboard/pod to access the in-service-mesh datasource/pod.

Comment: Maybe you are using Istio with Mutual TLS authentication? if so you can't reach your Postgresql instance outside of the mesh.

Comment: You are right, we are currently using mutual TLS authentication, our other option is to move the postgres instance outside the service mesh, but if so, are there significant implications as to how our application pods communicate with it?

Comment: I think Istio is correctly handling service that is outside of the service mesh, to check you can connect to the PostgreSQL pod and try to fetch content via HTTP, I everything is ok you can safely remove PostgreSQL from the service mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PERMISSIVE` mTLS mode - see https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/mtls-migration/.